# Date format is not in proper format while downloading using velocity template

Tags: java, xml, velocity

I have predefined velocity template(.vm file) which is read to create and download as a xml file. The template has a date field to which value is assigned as `6/5/19 5:21 PM`, but when this is downloaded as xml its displaying as `6&#x2f;5&#x2f;19 5&#x3a;21 PM`

The object code in vm file.

`<StatusDate>$!object.statusDate</StatusDate>`

Please guide me for solving this issue. 
Thanks!

Comment: It looks that the slash and the colon are escaped as xml-entities. That is not done by Velocity so there has to be some configuration or tool used to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Sascha in his comment, this encoding is probably done *after* the Velocity rendering.

But it could also be done *during* the rendering, typically by a [Reference Insertion Handler](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.1/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/event/ReferenceInsertionEventHandler.html), an object which is called for each rendered reference value. Such a handler must be registered against Velocity with the configuration key `eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class`. For instance:

```
eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class = org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.EscapeXmlReference
```

Comment: I have already added code to escape the special characters by exending the EscapeXmlReference. But I think won't consider the backslash or colon, only these: &  < > " '